# ubuntu 11.10 freezes when shutting down

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, logout

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed on INSPIRON N5030. When I try to shutdown/restart from user login menu, it freezes and after a while it shows the user login menu again. This happens only if i have logged in two accounts. Even after logging off each, this happens again.Please put forward a solution for this...

Comment: have you checked the system error log

Comment: This is probably a result of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/855556 ("Restart" and "Shut Down" don't work if anyone else is logged in)